# Incorrect syntax near 'THEN' in IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a procedure to change a user's password but I am having a bit of difficulty finishing it off, I have the general gist of it but having a few syntax errors. This is my procedure;

```
CREATE PROC ChangePassword
    @User_Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @OldPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @NewPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @ResponseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF ((
        SELECT PasswordHash
        FROM dbo.Users
        WHERE dbo.Users.user_name=@User_Name)=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@OldPassword + (
            SELECT CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(50))
            FROM dbo.Users
            WHERE dbo.Users.user_name = @User_Name)))
    THEN
        UPDATE dbo.Users SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@NewPassword + (
        SELECT CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(50))
        FROM dbo.Users
        WHERE dbo.Users.user_name = @User_Name))
        SET @ResponseMessage = 'Password Changed Successfully'
    ELSE
        SET @ResponseMessage = 'Old Password did not match'
END
```

It basically checks if the hash of the old password they entered matches the hash of the actual old password and if it does then update it with a hash of the new password but I am having a bit of difficulty with the `IF` statement as I am getting compilation errors underneath the `THEN` and `ELSE` saying `incorrect syntax near 'THEN'` and `ELSE` respectively, could someone provide some guidance to fix this?

Comment: Also, ["THEN" isn't a keyword in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql). You just use `IF` and `ELSE` with `BEGIN` and `END` blocks if necessary.

Comment: There is no IF THEN in SQL. It's IF... ELSE or CASE WHEN...THEN.

Comment: @vkp it is checking if the selected value matches the value from the hashbytes function

Comment: @JacobH so i am going to have to rewrite it to be a `case`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No, a `CASE` expression can't be used instead of an `IF`, it's an expression

Comment: @Lamak so how would i create the desired logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability and easiness of maintenance you could do something like the following:

```
CREATE PROC ChangePassword
    @User_Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @OldPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @NewPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @ResponseMessage NVARCHAR(250) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- To keep track of the old password hash in the User table
    DECLARE @oldPasswordHash VARBINARY(8000) = (SELECT PasswordHash FROM dbo.Users WHERE User_Name = @User_Name);

    -- To obtain the salt used with the HASHBYTES function and passwords
    DECLARE @salt NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT Salt FROM dbo.Users WHERE User_Name = @User_Name);

    -- To check if the old password hash in the User table matches the the @OldPassword passed by the user
    DECLARE @computedOldPasswordHash VARBINARY(8000) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @OldPassword + @salt);

    -- Check if old password hash equals the computed old password hash
    IF (@oldPasswordHash = @computedOldPasswordHash)
        BEGIN
            -- new password hash
            DECLARE @newPasswordHash VARBINARY(8000) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @NewPassword + @salt);

            UPDATE dbo.Users
            SET PasswordHash = @newPasswordHash
            WHERE User_Name = @User_Name

            SET @ResponseMessage = 'Password Changed Successfully'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ResponseMessage = 'Old Password did not match'
        END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL language then is not used for the IF statement.
Then it's using in the case structure, okay?
Change your then to begin

Staying that way

```
CREATE PROC ChangePassword
    @User_Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @OldPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @NewPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @ResponseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF ((
        SELECT PasswordHash
        FROM dbo.Users
        WHERE dbo.Users.user_name=@User_Name)=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@OldPassword + (
            SELECT CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(50))
            FROM dbo.Users
            WHERE dbo.Users.user_name = @User_Name)))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Users SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@NewPassword + (
        SELECT CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(50))
        FROM dbo.Users
        WHERE dbo.Users.user_name = @User_Name))
        SET @ResponseMessage = 'Password Changed Successfully'
END
    ELSE
BEGIN
        SET @ResponseMessage = 'Old Password did not match'
END --END ELSE

END --end proc
```

Comment: you still need a logical function in the `IF` instead of just a `SELECT`

Comment: @Lamak there is a logical check. It is just formatted so horribly by the OP that is nearly hidden. =HASHBYTES....

Comment: Will the update only happen if the condition is met?